# Downloaded versions of .NETFrameworkare not seen by Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I downloaded some .NET versions from official website (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks?cid=getdotnetsdk) and installed them. However, I cannot find them inside Visual Studio with target framework menu in my c# project's properties.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8zJi.png)

Also I installed some SDKs and Targeting packs using Visual Studio Installer but they are not seen too.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o55rK.png)